# What are the advantages of using Spring Data REST over Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I know that spring data rest will export your repositories as REST services..but i want to know advantages of that over use of spring data jpa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a fruit-salad-to-buffet comparison as the technologies solve completely different problems:

[Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) eases working with JPA on top of Spring. It exposes a repository programming model which allows you to build Java APIs to access data in relational databases.

[Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) builds on top of the repository abstraction (not being tied to JPA at all) and exposes Spring MVC based REST resources following common patterns via a HTTP.

I suggest to skim through the getting started [guides for Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and [Spring Data REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) to play with both of them and get a feel for the problems they solve.

Answer (score 6):

Spring-Data-JPA is just one "flavour" of how you will persist your data. Among others, there are also MongoDB, Neo4J, etc. So as Oliver explained, Spring-Data is about how and where you keep your data.

On the other hand, Spring-Data REST is implementation, how to expose that data through REST using best practices.

Hope this clarifies a bit.